# Have difficulty turning tuple into indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, slice

I'm having difficulty turning tuple into indexing in order to output a new list.
(I just don't mind the Python code format here, I'm sorry)
For example, the input list is `[0, 3, 4, 2, 1, 5]` and the input tuple is `(0,2)`
I wanna get the list of index 0 to index 2 of the input list, I mean my expected output is `[0, 3, 4]`. Does anyone know how to convert the tuple `(0,2)` into a continuous indexing to get the expected output?
Here's my way to complete that:

`final_list = [input_list[i] for i in input_tuple]`

I knew my way to do it is wrong, I couldn't think up another way to do it. Could you guys help me out?

Comment: Does your tuple size is always two?

Comment: So... essentially `input_list[input_tuple[0]:input_tuple[1]+1]`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if it can help:

```py
start, end = tpl     # your tuple 

final_list = lst[start: end+1]   # lst is your input_list 
>>>final_list
[0, 3, 4]
```

Comment: @Xiangyin: That *is* Python. What, did you think this answer was in Javascript?

Comment: @Xiangyin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: `lst` is your original list variable name. (input_list?)

Comment: Please tell us what is `not working`?  Show us the statements.